# Shopware6 Error when Updating a product using DAL

Tags: product, data-access-layer, shopware

While trying to update a product using the Shopware6 DAL recommended syntax, I am getting this error :
**Expected primary key field id for definition Shopware\Core\Content\Product\ProductDefinition not provided**

Here is the code :

```
/ @var EntityRepositoryInterface $productRepository /
$productRepository = $this->container->get('product.repository');
                    $productRepository->update(
                    [
                            [
                            'id' => '4667A4C753544F3BA40ED9441F79611D',
                            'name' => 'Woush'
                            ],
                    ],
                    \Shopware\Core\Framework\Context::createDefaultContext()
                    );
```

I am providing the correct ID related to the product I want to update. I don't understand why I get this error.

Does someone have a solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if in the official documentation of Shopware6 (https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-platform-dev-en/how-to/creating-entities-dal#working-with-relations), the "id" is written in lowercase, you have to write it like this **"Id"**.

Comment: Carefull: Shopware clearly defines it as "id", not "Id". Naming it "Id" only solves the problem since you provide no "id", so Shopware generates a new one and hence has no conflict. But this works only seemingly: You'll have a new entry every time.